# form php not working [array]

Tags: php, html

I need to show the `var_dump` with 'selected country' , 
but i can't do it ,  because the problem in the $res (array) $id

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST['submit']))
{
    $id = $_POST['cata'];

    $api = new SoapClient ( 'http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' );
    $res = $api->GetCitiesByCountry(array( 'CountryName' =>"$id"));

    var_dump($res);
}
?> 

<form action="" name="cata">
    <select>
        <option>Israel</option>
        <option>Egypt</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input id='sumbit' name='submit' type='submit' value='tim'>
</form>
```

---

still not working , but i think the problem in

```html
  $res = $api->GetCitiesByCountry(array( 'CountryName' =>"$id"));
```

Comment: There is no name in the select element. Refer how to write select element at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: not working ...

Comment: Also you have I assume a typo at `<input id='sumbit'` should probably be `submit`

Comment: I think OP is now complaining about the webservice not working

Comment: If you want to var_dump the country then you must try var_dump($id) I am not sure what the $res is.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to put name as `cata` to select tag not to form tag

```
<select name="cata"><option>Israel</option><option>Egypt</option></select>
```

Also put method as `post` in form tag

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

I think web service is working : http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL&CountryName=Israel

Answer (score 0):

define `cata` as a `select` name not a `form` name

so define form like below

```
<form action="" method="post"> //<--- also set method for retrieving data in php 
  <select name="cata"> //<--here is the name field
      <option>Israel</option>
      <option>Egypt</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input id='sumbit' name='submit' type='submit' value='tim'>
</form>
```

and set in php

```
$id = $_POST['cata']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code snippet. It should work for you. What was still missing in the "Alive to Die" snippet is that the values for the options were not set.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); //check all type of error
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); // display those errors

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id = $_POST['cata'];
        $api = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL');
        $res = $api->GetCitiesByCountry(array('CountryName' => "$id"));
        var_dump($res);
    }
?> 
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="cata">
        <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input id='sumbit' name='submit' type='submit' value='tim'>
</form>
```

If still this code does not run then please check if you have php_soap.dll extension enable. To install this package run sudo apt-get install php-soap and then uncomment the following line from the php.ini file
extension=php_soap.dll